# How to draw something over all components of a JPanel

Tags: java, swing

How to draw something over all components of a Panel?

In the code below I tried to do this overriding the `paintComponent` method, I call `super.paintComponent(g)` hoping this will draw all components added as part of the constructor, but still my X stays below the image.

```java
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Stack extends JPanel {

    private final JLabel some_text = new JLabel("Some very long text that will be covered", JLabel.LEFT);
    private final JLabel some_icon = new JLabel((Icon)null, JLabel.CENTER);
    public static final String COMPASS_URL = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f8/Compass_Rose_English_North.svg/240px-Compass_Rose_English_North.svg.png";

    public Stack() throws IOException {
        super(new GridBagLayout());

        URL compassUrl = new URL(COMPASS_URL);
        BufferedImage compassImage = ImageIO.read(compassUrl);
        ImageIcon compassIcon = new ImageIcon(compassImage);
        some_icon.setIcon(compassIcon);

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;

        add(some_icon, c);

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        add(some_text, c);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(15));
        g2.drawLine(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        g2.drawLine(this.getWidth(), 0, 0, this.getHeight());
        g2.dispose();
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI() throws IOException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyFrame");
        frame.getContentPane().add(new Stack());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    createAndShowUI();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Is there a way to bring my X to the foreground or to wait for `super.paintComponent(g)` to paint everything, and then run the code that draws the X?

Thanks,
Roberto

Comment: What is the desired effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `paint(…)` method of your JPanel:

```
protected void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);

    // add custom painting code here
}
```

The `paint(…)` method invokes the `paintChildren(…)` method so your custom code will be executed after all the components on the panel are painted.

See [A Closer Look at the Painting Mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  I made the following changes.

- Drew the image in `paintComponent` as opposed to `setIcon`.
- positioned the image to center it.
- used `setPreferredSize` for real panel size (setting frame size includes borders which is probably not what you wanted).
- used `RenderingHints` in `paintComponent` to smooth out edges of cross.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Stack2 extends JPanel {

    private final JLabel some_text = new JLabel(
            "Some very long text that will be covered", JLabel.LEFT);
    private final JLabel some_icon =
            new JLabel((Icon) null, JLabel.CENTER);
    public static final String COMPASS_URL =
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f8/Compass_Rose_English_North.svg/240px-Compass_Rose_English_North.svg.png";
    BufferedImage compassImage;

    public Stack2() throws IOException {
        super(new GridBagLayout());

        URL compassUrl = new URL(COMPASS_URL);
        compassImage = ImageIO.read(compassUrl);
//        ImageIcon compassIcon = new ImageIcon(compassImage);
//        some_icon.setIcon(compassIcon);

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;

        add(some_icon, c);

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        add(some_text, c);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.drawImage(compassImage,
                (400 - compassImage.getWidth()) / 2,
                (400 - compassImage.getHeight()) / 2, null);
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(15));
        g2.drawLine(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        g2.drawLine(this.getWidth(), 0, 0, this.getHeight());
        g2.dispose();
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI() throws IOException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyFrame");
        Stack2 panel = new Stack2();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    createAndShowUI();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand that drawing everything inside the `paintComponent` gives me control over the order in which the components are drawn, but it's not an option in my case. Adding or not the big X on top is a feature of my JPanel, doesn't matter what was added before.

Comment: Could not tell that was a requirement from your question.